# MongoDB - field reflecting insertion order

Tags: mongodb

I have an application that continuously inserts documents to a MongoDB collection.

I'm looking for a way to query documents following their insertion order.

The candidates I wanted to use:

- the `_id` field
- a creation date field
- a sequence number (auto increment)

The `_id` field is not a good candidate as the docs say. A creation date field could have been a good candidate, however the fact that clocks may not be in sync may break the order. Regarding sequence numbers, the docs propose two approaches: counters and optimistic loop. The counters approach doesn't guarantee the insertion order because a document `D1` may be inserted after another document `D2` even if `D1.seq < D2.seq`. For example, if `D1` seizes sequence number 5, then `D2` seizes sequence number 6, then `D2` is inserted, then `D1` is inserted. The optimistic loop approach is crazy in case of heavy insert environment.

Is there another approach?

---

**EDIT:**

The approach using counters is problematic. Consider the following scenario. I have an application `A` that continuously inserts documents to a collection. I also have another application `B` that continuously polls for documents from the same collection. Application `A` is multi threaded. Two threads `T1` and `T2` are about to insert documents `D1` and `D2`, respectively. In the middle of insertions, application `B` asks for more documents. Assume the following ordering of operations:

1. Thread `A-T1` seizes next sequence number `N`
2. Thread `A-T2` seizes next sequence number `N+1`
3. Thread `A-T2` inserts `D2`
4. Application `B` asks for documents with `seq >= N` (assume last document processed has seq number `N-1`) and receives `D2` (`D1` has not been inserted yet)
5. Thread `A-T1` inserts `D1`
6. Application `B` asks for documents with `seq >= N+2` (since the last processed document has seq number `N+1`)

In this case, `D1` will never be processed.

Comment: If i understand you correctly you need a way how to know in what order documents were created and then saved. I suggest you to generate _id by yourself.. For example when server starts you get last _id inserted(or greatest one. Like 1505). Then you just on each document istert increase counter. And you are good to go. Even if some documents failed to save, you can save it to some JSON file and resave later on. _id will be generated by that time and you will have order system. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see how your approach is different than the third approach in the question.

Comment: Yep it's the same just more words there.

Comment: @MickaelMarrache I have exactly the same problem, what solution did you pick for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you expect tens of inserts per second, optimistic lock is the only way.

Otherwise clock sync could be a better idea.

Considering counters, could you elaborate how it affect your application, if `D1` is persisted after `D2`, since you guarantee order of acquiring the sequential number? The "insert" operation in mongodb itself have multiple stages, and you can go as deep as rely on journaling.

**EDIT**

Would you consider [tailable cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/tailable-cursors/) as an option for application `B`? It does not answer the question directly, but it may solve the problem behind the question.

**EDIT 2**

Then you probably need to use a message queue of any kind to communicate between apps, like on the image. It may be an overkill, but if you are sure that optimistic lock is a bottleneck, then it may be acceptable.

On the image below:

1. applications `A` insert a document *in any order* and retrieve unique object id from mongo client.
2. applications `A` send objectID to the queue *in any order*
3. applications `B` get next objectID from the queue
4. applications `B` fetch document by ID from the database

[image]

**EDIT 3**

Finally, you may consider to add status to the document and shift optimistic lock to application `B`:

1. retrieve and objectID of unprocessed document: `db.collection.findOne({status: null}, {})`
2. change it's status to 'processing'

   ```
   db.collection.findAndModify({
       query: { _id: objectId, status: null }, 
       update: { $set: { status: 'processing' }}
   })
   ```

   if it returns null - the document is being processed by another instance of `B`, so return to step 1
3. process the document and update it's status to 'done':

   ```
   db.collection.findAndModify({
       query: { _id: objectId, status: 'processing' }, 
       update: { $set: { status: 'done' }}
   })
   ```

With this approach you don't care about exact sequence at all. You can add a timestamp, or relay on ObjectId to sort documents in step 1, if you like to process documents in order. It may not be exact order of course, but you don't need it to guarantee all documents are processed.

Comment: Regarding your comment about optimistic loop, I think it's the opposite - ie optimistic loop is inefficient with lot of concurrent inserts because it will probably loop multiple time before being able to insert the document without duplicate error.

Comment: The reason for optimistic lock vs timestamp is NTP may not be sufficient when you count on milliseconds, but I see you point about performnce. Try to avoid premature optimisation untill you **prove** it is a problem. 
Regarding your edit - how come application `B` is aware of the sequence number? It solely belongs to application `A` domain. `B` can only ask to return e.g. latest 1000 documents, ordered by sequence number. Any other filter like "older than timestamp" is also ok, assuming you add a timestamp for filtering. The sequence number is used for sorting only.

Comment: Tailable cursors are only available for capped collections according to the doc - irrelevant for me :(

Comment: B can't simply ask for latest 1000 documents. It asks for more documents after the last it received. The important point here is that I don't want documents to be inserted in the range of documents already covered by B. If such documents are inserted, they will never be visible by B. Therefore, I need to define an ordering such that documents are inserted following this ordering.

Comment: It seems you are using a wrong tool. I have updated the answer with possible solution.

Comment: Added a 3rd option for mongodb-only approach.